# How to get FILE * from NSFileHandle *?

Tags: ios, nsfilehandle

An old parser relies on a `FILE *` to work. However, the Dropbox Sync API for iOS returns a `NSFileHandle *` instead of a `FILE *` as a file handle.

So I try to use `fileDescriptor` of a `NSFileHandle`:

> **- (NSFileHandle *)readHandle:(DBError **)error**
>
> Returns a read-only file handle for the file. If the file is not
>   cached then the method will block until the file is downloaded.
>   Returns
>
> A file handle if the file can be read, or nil if an error occurred.

and passed as a `FILE *`:

```
- (void)loadDBFile:(DBFile *)dbFile
{
    DBError *dbError;
    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [dbFile readHandle:&dbError];
    if (fileHandle) {
         FILE *file = fileHandle.fileDescriptor;
         fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); // EXE_BAD_ACCESS here!
         // ...
    }
}
```

However, there is an `EXE_BAD_ACCESS` at the `fseek` line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fileDescriptor` returns the underlying file descriptor, a simple integer, not a `FILE` object (which wraps a file descriptor, but isn't the same thing). Use [`fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/fdopen.html) to obtain a `FILE` object from the file descriptor:

```
FILE *file = fdopen([filehandle fileDescriptor], "r"); // Create a read-only FILE object
```